# AngularJS - make md-toolbar sticky and pages within ng-view scrollable (on an iPhone)

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I have prepared a Plunkr example but I need help with scrolling of the pages inside the **ng-view** directive.

Please start the "embedded" application on an actual iPhone5, iPhone6 or iPad.

https://plnkr.co/edit/WXtQxVcdgyvnaajbs4eJ?p=preview

Right now **md-toolbar** is scrolling with the entire site but I want to make it sticky to the top while all pages inside the **ng-view** directive should be scrollable.

Update: Mike Feltman suggested to fix the md-toolbar but this doesn't help.

```
<md-toolbar style="position: fixed;">
```

The screen-shot shows the problem. Right now the entire page is scrolling (red arrow) but what I want is that pages scoll inside **ng-view** (green arrow)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something is wrong with your plunker. The link doesn't work all the time and the file references open the wrong files.

Comment: What about this link? https://plnkr.co/edit/WXtQxVcdgyvnaajbs4eJ?p=preview To test it it must be viewed in the embedded view though.

Comment: Yeah, that works and my answer works with that code as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your md-toolbar element to:

```
  <md-toolbar style="position: fixed;">
```

or define a css class for fixed and apply the style to your toolbar.

You can also try using $mdSticky with a directive. This is probably not exactly what you need, but will get you close.

```
angular.module("yourApp").directive('sticky', Sticky)

function Sticky($mdSticky) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $mdSticky(scope, element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work on the iPhone though. I started the embedded link on the iPhone but it doesn't scoll  ;-(

Comment: From the plunker or the actual page itself?

Comment: Hi Mike I opened the embedded link https://embed.plnkr.co/WXtQxVcdgyvnaajbs4eJ/ on my iPhone and it doesn't scroll, while it works fine on the Chrome dev tool simulator. Your suggestion, to make the **<md-toolbar>** sticky works but I'm trying to figure out why injected pages into **<ng-view>** don't scroll on the iPhone.